# Recently google has changed his page speed algorithm

Tags: pagespeed

```
Recently google has changed page speed or page insights algorithm. Even if you keep your css or js in footer below closing of your tag . It will show block render blocking.
```

from last one year my page speed was 90 on bothy mobile and desktop. Now from two days it was showing 50 due to render blocking.

```
   Even In pingdom its showing 93.
```

Could somebody assist me........On this please

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: doyalpouchmachine.com...... previously speed of this page is 100 out of 100

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder hi sir have you checked that

Comment: It seems to be mad about one JQuery file. It shows 85 on my machine for Desktop and 95 for mobile, for what its worth...

Comment: but its in footer right

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder  main thread if i am removing this jquery then its showing below js or css

Comment: Hmm maybe it's saying that in order to render the elements it needs to load that JQuery so it is 'render-blocking' in that sense? I have no idea ha!

Comment: even i am writing only one css file its showing same thing... can mark it as upvoted. so others can help on this

Comment: hi, have you found any solution

Answer (score 1):

Wicked fast server you got there.

Requests numbers 19-22 and 33 & 34 are css and font files.  Rendering is held up by these css and font files. Move the .css and .woff links to the top of the `<head>`

[image]

Comment: That's how you fix the Rendering Blocking.  It should not create any error.

Comment: I do not know if this is related but the is an HTML error on a coupld of script `<link>`s " line 297 column 113 - Error: Element “script” must not have attribute “defer” unless attribute “src” is also specified."  Using non-standard crap like "rocketscript" does not help matters.  jQuery is "text/javascript", not that it should matter, it's just bad practice to use non-standard crap.  Moving CSS to the top of the `<head>`  should not cause an error.  That's why I do not use jQuery or 3rd party crap.  If there is an error it's MY error and I will know how to fix it because I wrote the code.